# Parsing IP address and ranges in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, ip

I'm writing a script that returns an IP's country from whois.iana.org and regional whois.
No problems with that.

To minimize queries I would like to be able to **store the ip range** from the whois server and **store the returned country for that range in a database**, so in case another ip adress from that same class is done I can just search it in the database first, rather than sending a request to the whois server.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    $ip = @$_GET['ip']."\r\n";
echo whois_get($ip);

//Open connection to whois server and fetch data
function whois_query($ip, $server) {
    $fp = @fsockopen($server, 43, $errno, $errdesc);

if ($fp === false) {
    error_report('Error opening the socket: ' . $errno . ' - ' . $errdesc . "\n");
    return false;
}

if (fputs($fp, $ip) === false) {
    error_report('Error writing to the socket' . "\n");
    return false;
}
$answer = '';
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $answer .= fread($fp, 8192);
}
fclose($fp);
return $answer;

};
function whois_get($ip) {
    $string = whois_query($ip, 'whois.iana.org');
    preg_match('/whois\..+/', $string, $whoisServer);
    if (array_key_exists('0', $whoisServer)) {
        if ($whoisServer[0] == "whois.arin.net") {
             $ip = "n ".$ip; 
        }
        $whoisInfo = whois_query($ip, $whoisServer[0]);
        $country = getCountry($whoisInfo);
        return "<b>Country:</b>".$country." \r\n";

    } else {
    return "UNKNOWN";
}
}

function getCountry($data){
    preg_match('/ountry\:\s*[A-Z]{2}/', $data, $country);
    $whoisCountry = $country[0];
    $whoisCountry = preg_replace('/ountry\:/', '', $whoisCountry);
    $whoisCountry = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $whoisCountry);
    return $whoisCountry;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do this for both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses? I know you can not use regex here.

**How do I parse the data returned from the whois server?**

**How do I search in my local database to determine which range the ip belongs to?**

Comment: How is that C or Perl?

Comment: it isn't but I thought somebody that works in these languages might have an idea...

Comment: hi just some guy!
you have still that problem or solved ?